# Trying to open window on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to open a javascript application in it's own window. I've created a button and attached an onclick event to it but nothing happens when I click on it. I through in an alert to troubleshoot but that doesn't launch either.

In the console I get error: jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found) but I always get that so I usually ignore it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="$1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>$2</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://hosted.test.ca/kc/MD/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://hosted.teste.ca/kc/MD/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var $launch = $('#launchButton');
            $launch.click(function(){
                alert("opening ManagementDash");
                var url = 'https://hosted.test.ca/kc/MD/SiteAssets/mgmtDash.html';
                window.open(url,'ManagementDash','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=100%,height=100%');
                return  false;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="launchButton" >Launch MDash</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which browser are you using?  IE has problems with the middle parameter you show as `ManagementDash`.

Comment: Wrap this in a DOM ready handler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are firing your script before the element has been loaded in the dom.

Try wrapping your code in document ready or place it at the bottom of the page.

If you check http://jsfiddle.net/tutZE/ your code works fine as it adds the document ready for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $launch = $('#launchButton');
            $launch.click(function(){
                alert("opening ManagementDash");
                var url = 'https://hosted.test.ca/kc/MD/SiteAssets/mgmtDash.html';
                window.open(url,'ManagementDash','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=100%,height=100%');
                return  false;
            });

});
```

Another option is to use .on or delegate method method in jquery

http://api.jquery.com/on/

[http://api.jquery.com/delegate/](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: No problem dont forget to mark as correct, and good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have jQuery loaded and wrap your script in `$( document ).ready` function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

            var $launch = $('#launchButton');

            $launch.click(function(){
                alert("opening ManagementDash");
                var url = 'https://hosted.test.ca/kc/MD/SiteAssets/mgmtDash.html';
                window.open(url,'ManagementDash','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=100%,height=100%');
                return  false;
            });

 });
```